# Error filtering a ForeignKey with UUID as pk

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm using django-filters to filter data and display it in a table. One of the values is a ForeignKey that has as pk an UUID. When I use **lookup_expr='icontains'** then I get the following error:

*"Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains"*

How can I use lookup_expr='icontains' for a ForeignKey with a UUID pk?

Thank you in advance.

models:

```
class Data(models.Model):

    data_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    data_device_id = models.ForeignKey(Device, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)


class Device(models.Model):
    device_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Filter:

```
class DataFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    data_id = django_filters.CharFilter(label='Data id', lookup_expr='icontains')
    data_device_id = django_filters.CharFilter(label='Device id', lookup_expr='icontains') #ERROR HERE 

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = {'data_id','data_device_id'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify that the `__icontains` works on the primary key, so:

```
class DataFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    data_id = django_filters.CharFilter(label='Data id', lookup_expr='icontains')
    data_device_id = django_filters.CharFilter(
        label='Device id',
        lookup_expr='icontains',
        #                           ↓ apply the lookup on the primary key
        field_name='data_device_id__pk'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = {'data_id','data_device_id'}
```